# What's the difference between the signed and unsigned right shift operator in Jana?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bitwise shift operators. Signed and unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244387/bitwise-shift-operators-signed-and-unsigned)
>   [Difference between >>> and >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and)

Given:

```
int i = -1000;
```

What's the difference between:

```
i = i >> 4;
```

and

```
i = i >>> 4;
```

?

This particular example isn't important, I'm just trying to understand the difference between the signed and unsigned bit shifts.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: @aerain it only matters for negatives; *signed* right-shift is *arithmetic*, while *unsigned* is *logical*.