# Counting 1's and 0's in a bit sequence

Tags: java, bit

These two methods are from [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/). I wish to count the number of 0's and 1's in a bit sequence.

For example, for the following sequence `00000000000000000011011100111101` ,
I thought after removing the leading zeros I would get:

- 2 Ones
- 1 Zero
- 3 Ones
- 2 Zero
- 4 Ones
- 1 Zero
- 1 One

I though this result is obtained by subtracting the the **p** values that store the counted zeros and ones.

But I don't get these values exactly from the *ffstrl* method. What am I missing ?

```
private  void ffstrl(int x){
    int k,p;
    p = 0;
    while(x != 0){
        k = nlz(x); //Count zeros
        x = x << k ;
        p = p + k;
        k = nlz(~x); //Count Ones

        x = x << k;
        p = p + k;
    }
}

 int nlz(int x){
    if( x == 0){
        return 32;
    }
    int n = 0;
    if( x <= 0x0000FFFF) { n =  n + 16; x = x << 16;}
    if( x <= 0x00FFFFFF) { n =  n + 8; x = x << 8;}
    if( x <= 0x0FFFFFFF) { n =  n + 4; x = x << 4;}
    if( x <= 0x3FFFFFFF) { n =  n + 2; x = x << 2;}
    if( x <= 0x7FFFFFFF) { n =  n + 1;}
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Which programmer language do you (want to) use?

Comment: What are the values you actually get from your method?

Comment: Looks like c code ported to java with no respect to `unsigned`

Comment: @Konstantin Yes. Could that be the problem ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan for example I see you're using signed left shift operators here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244387/bitwise-shift-operators-signed-and-unsigned

Comment: And of course, you can always run this in debugger and see what really happens

Comment: I am trying to use **p** to capture starting position and ending position of the sequence of 1's and 0's. But the value in p is not exact. So if the sequence of 0's start at the 19th position and ends at the 21st position the result is off by 1 or 2 positions. It is difficult to reconcile.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show input data, output data & code that produced it, in this case including size of int.