# what is 0xffffffff and << in java

Tags: java

I'm wondering about this part of a code (it's an IP mask code)

```
int mask = 0xffffffff << (32 - prefix);
System.out.println("Prefix=" + prefix);
System.out.println("Address=" + ip);
int value = mask;
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{ 
(byte)(value >>> 24), (byte)(value >> 16 & 0xff), 
(byte)(value >> 8 & 0xff),
(byte)(value & 0xff) };
try {
InetAddress netAddr = InetAddress.getByAddress(bytes);
System.out.println("Mask=" + netAddr.getHostAddress());
```

Comment: _"i wish that someone can put comments // after each line"_ SO is not a code translator service. What part is unclear? Did you search what does << do ? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitwise shift operators. Signed and unsigned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244387/bitwise-shift-operators-signed-and-unsigned)

Answer (score 4):

`<<` is the Left Shift operator. `>>` is the Right Shift operator. You can read about bit shifting in Java [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

0xffffffff is an [hexadecimal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

Answer (score 1):

These are hexadecimal numbers and bitwise operations.

Hexadecimal numbers use a number system with radix `16`. Thus `0xffff` means:

```
(((15*16+15)*16+15)*16+15)*16+15=65'535
```

This is mainly useful because a nibble (one hexadecimal digit), maps exactly on four bits. Since `F` is `1111` in binary, `0xffff` means `1111 1111 1111 1111` (or the last 16 bits are one).

`<<` and `>>` are bitwise arithmetic shifts. If you specify `0xffff<<8`, it means you shift the number eight bits to the left thus:

```
     1111 1111 1111 1111                ff ff ff ff
<<                     8             <<           8
------------------------             --------------
1111 1111 1111 1111 0000             ff ff ff ff 00
```

`>>` is a shift in the opposite direction, **but** the highest bit also determines the value of the new bits at the left. In case the left bits should be zero, you need to use the **logical right shift** (`>>>`).

Other bitwise operations include `|`, `&`, `~` and `^` (not to be confused with `&&`, `||`, etc.).